# I need a batch script that creates files from a a list and enters the first row of the text

Tags: batch-file, createfile

I am looking for a batch script that creates files from a a list. c:\test\list.txt and also the first row of the text to be included in the file, the text is devided by TAB from the title.
(ps. I am using German characters)

- aaaa this text goes to file aaaa
- bbbb this text goes to file bbbb
- cccc this text goes to file ccc

I found this batch here, which works great, 
what I need is to enter the text in the files and the
German characters to be displayed properly

@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (_.txt) do (type nul>"%%a.txt")

Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code puts strings in the files.

```
@echo off setlocal
chcp 1252
SET "_TAB=  "
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=%_TAB%" %%a in (List.txt) do (
type nul>"%%a.txt"
echo %%b>>%%a.txt
)
```

If you copy the code from here, be carefull about that the space after equal sign should be TAB character where the code is `SET "_TAB= "`

If your Windows use CP1250 then change 1252 to 1250 where the code is `chcp 1252`. This solution may work with German.

Comment: Thank you, man, that works!
but I still have the issue with the filename characters
ex.
abführen.txt    looks like    abf├╝hren.txt

Comment: ...and also it doesn't enter in the textfile all the text but just the filename

Comment: "the first row of the text to be included in the file" Explain detailed please which text from which file to which file. This code creates a file of which name is a string taken from a row of a text file and puts same string in it. The character problem arises from the CP1252 which windows uses is interpreted as OEM850 by batch interpreter  I think. (I think a German language uses these character encodings.) I am thinking for a solution for this situation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't explained it very well
the list has
two columns, the first one has the name for the file
and the second has the content for each file, like in excel.
(I don't know if that if possible from excel)

<filename> <content>
<filename> <content>
<filename> <content>
...  ...

(thank you for your time)

Comment: @Aimilus But the encoding problem is a problem for me also. I may find a solution. But it may take time.

Comment: If you copy the code from here, be careful that the space after equal sign should be TAB caharacter where the code is `_TAB=    `

Comment: @Aimilus There is a solution for encoding problem: If you create your text file from scratch make it encoded OEM850. To do this use notebook++ and after open the file in it and select from menu Encoding->Character Set->West European->OEM850; then save it. Everytime you open it in notepad++ and select same encoding. I think it will work. (I think OEM850 is DOS encoding for German language.)

Comment: @Aimilus I edited my code. If your Windows use CP1250 then change 1252 to 1250. This solution does not work in my language but it may work with German.

Comment: Thank you , it worked, you saved me a lot of time, but I did it with notepad++, (I must start to learn batch files)